# Why does this image appear so small?

Tags: graphics

I am trying to insert an image, scaling it to the text size and rotating it, using the following example:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth,height=\textheight,keepaspectratio,angle=90]{bhuta1.JPG}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

The image is [here](http://www1.tantric-studies.uni-hamburg.de/ressources/bhuta1.JPG). As can be seen below the image appears very small only, why is that so, and how do I fix it?

[image: Output]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your image makes it look smaller than I expect. and smaller than I get with pdflatex, but you have the arguments the wrong way round, they are read left to right so you need

[image]

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=\textheight,height=\textwidth,keepaspectratio,angle=90]{bhuta1.JPG}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

with the width based on text *height* as you scale before rotating.

Comment: I use `xelatex`, and it seems the problem is connected with that, as with `pdflatex` and your suggested change (which I had actually already tried out with xelatex, without it solving the problem) the result is fine.

Comment: @muk.li there have been a few issues with image inclusion in xetex but I just tried it with the xelatex in texlive 2015 pretest and it is identical to the pdflatex result. the problem was determining the initial size from the jpeg data, so it probably works to remove the width= and height= and just put scale=5 or whatever value works

Comment: Using the `scale` option to `includegraphics` doesn't help. I converted the jpeg to png, that seemed to work, I hope without losses to the image quality, I'll have to look a bit into that. Or else I could maybe just use `pdflatex` for that file.

Comment: I think the more intuitive solution is to make the `angle=90` the first argument and base the height on the textheight.